# Returning IQueryable<T> From Generic Method

Tags: c#, generics, iqueryable

So, I have the following code:

```
    private readonly Dictionary<string, IGame> _gameLookup = new Dictionary<string, IGame>();

    public T LookupGame<T>(string name) where T : IGame
    {
        if (name == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
        Type t = typeof(T);

        if (_gameLookup.Any(d => d.Key == name))
        {
            return (T)_gameLookup[name];
        }

        var newInstance = (T)AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetUnityContainer().Resolve(t, name);

        if (newInstance != null)
        {
            _gameLookup.Add(name, newInstance);

            return newInstance;
        }

        return default(T);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> ListGames<T>() where T : IGame
    {
        var games = _gameLookup.Where(d => d.GetType() == typeof (T));

        return (IQueryable<T>) games;
    }
```

My issue is with the ListGames method. (The LookupGame method is simply included for some context into what I'm doint.)

I can't for the life of me figure out how to manipulate things to get an IQueryable result. I've tried many things including the .AsQueryable() method, casting various things, etc.

Any insight into where I'm going wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need IQueryable<T> rather than IEnumerable<T>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code :

1. You call `GetType` on a `KeyValuePair<string, IGame>`, (As `_gameLookup` is a dictionary and so implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IGame>>` it's the type of `d`) while obviously you want to use it on the Values.
2. After Select the collection (`games`) is of type `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IGame>>` So you need to remove the `KeyValuePair` part
3. The cast won't work as you noted `AsQueryable` should be used.

Fixed code :

```
public IQueryable<T> ListGames<T>() where T : IGame
{
    return _gameLookup.Values
        .OfType<T>()
        .AsQueryable();
}
```

Comment: Ah... forest through the trees. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: The only version of `AsQueryable<T>` listed on MSDN take an `IEnumerable<T>` but `Values` only implements `IEnumerable<IGame>` so it won't find the overload with an error like `cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,UserQuery.IGame>.ValueCollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>'`

Answer (score 0):

The result type is `IEnumerable<Type>` which you can't cast to `IQueryable<T>` (not by a simple cast anyway)

You can try `AsQueryable()`:

```
return games.AsQueryable();
```